# Use uniq to filter adjacent lines in pipeline

Tags: grep, uniq

I'm trying to monitor theme changes using this command:

```shell
dbus-monitor --session "interface='org.freedesktop.portal.Settings', member=SettingChanged" | grep -o "uint32 ."
```

Output right now looks like this:

```
uint32 0
uint32 0
uint32 1
uint32 1
uint32 0
uint32 0
uint32 1
uint32 1
```

This output comes from theme toggling. The theme notification shows up twice for some reason. Now I want to pipe it to `uniq` so I only remain with a single entry like so:

```
uint32 0
uint32 1
uint32 0
uint32 1
```

However appending `uniq` at the end does not produce any output anymore.

```shell
dbus-monitor --session "interface='org.freedesktop.portal.Settings', member=SettingChanged" | grep -o "uint32 ." | uniq
```

From `man uniq`:

> Filter adjacent matching lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

`uniq` needs to buffer at least the last output line to be able to detect adjacent lines, I don't see any reason why it could not buffer it and pass it along the pipeline. I've tried tweaking line buffering as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295814/uniq-is-not-realtime-when-piped) but the results are still the same for me.

```shell
dbus-monitor --session "interface='org.freedesktop.portal.Settings', member=SettingChanged" | grep -o "uint32 ." | stdbuf -oL -i0 uniq
```

Comment: Try `dbus ... | awk 'BEGIN{last=""} $2!=last; {last=$2}'`

Comment: That didn't work for me unfortunately. I removed `uniq` and added `awk ...`. There is no output just like with `uniq`. I've toggled the button a few times to let initial values settle in.

Comment: How exactly did you try using stdbuf?

Comment: @muru I appended `stdbuf -oL -i0 uniq`. Updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @drewk your suggestion worked with grep being line buffered

Comment: your stdbuf is in the wrong place -- it needs to help the command whose output gets buffered

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's the usual behavior of many tools, inherited from default Standard C library behavior with functions manipulating [I/O streams](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) (`fopen(3)`, `fwrite(3)` ...). This is documented in `setvbuf(3)` (or a deprecated variant). Several *nixes tell the same: *[B](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setvbuf&manpath=SuSE%20Linux/i386%2011.3#DESCRIPTION)[S](https://man.openbsd.org/setvbuf.3#DESCRIPTION)[D](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/setvbuf.3.html), [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36874/setbuffer-3c.html), [GNU/Linux](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html#DESCRIPTION)..., but [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05) doesn't specify it and ISO/IEC 9899 is too elusive. [GNU tells](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html):

> Newly opened streams are normally fully buffered, with one exception:
> a stream connected to an interactive device such as a terminal is
> initially line buffered.

(Also, *stderr* is usually unbuffered in all the implementations. It doesn't matter for this Q/A.)

So for most text filtering commands (not all, for example `cat` doesn't have this behavior), whenever it's not the last command in a pipeline, its output is not line buffered anymore, and a linefeed will not trigger the immediate emission of data for the next command to process.

---

Here **the relevant command is not `uniq` but `grep`** because its output switches from terminal to non-terminal. GNU `grep` has an option to change this behavior: [`--line-buffered`](https://manpages.debian.org/grep/grep.1#line):

> `--line-buffered`
>
> Use line buffering on output. This can cause a performance penalty.

If the command doesn't have a specific option to choose the behavior, one can still use the command [`stdbuf`](https://manpages.debian.org/coreutils/stdbuf.1#EXAMPLES) which alters behavior by using `setvbuf(3)` through [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/ld.so.8#LD_PRELOAD) mechanism. To restore line-buffered behavior for a command that is not at the end of the pipeline, one can prefix this command with `stdbuf -oL` .

For OP's case:

```
dbus-monitor --session "interface='org.freedesktop.portal.Settings', member=SettingChanged" |
    grep --line-buffered -o "uint32 ." | uniq
```

or if this `grep` command didn't also have a specific option:

```
dbus-monitor --session "interface='org.freedesktop.portal.Settings', member=SettingChanged" |
    stdbuf -oL grep -o "uint32 ." | uniq
```

Note that in both cases, `uniq` being at the end of the pipeline didn't need any adjustment to its default behavior.

Should later the pipeline be augmented and `uniq` not be at the end anymore and thus not outputting to a terminal anymore, it would also change behavior and would require the same treatment. For example the line-buffered behavior of the `uniq` command alone on a terminal:

```
uniq
```

changes to full-buffered with :

```
uniq | cat
```

but can be reversed to line-buffered with:

```
stdbuf -oL uniq | cat
```